# Why according to JPA are Update/Delete operations are not allowed to set lock?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using Hibernate 5.2.15 with Spring Data JPA.

Let's say i need to implement voting system -  so  user just clicks "vote" button and "votes" column in DB now is +1.

I've implemented next method:

```
public interface CrudRestRepository extends Repository<Restaurant,Integer> {

@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("UPDATE Restaurant r SET r.votes=r.votes+1 where r.id=:restId ")
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
void addVoteToRestaurant(@Param("restId")int restId);
}
```

But when I tried to use this method i got next exception:

IllegalStateException: Illegal attempt to set lock mode on a non-SELECT query

So, I've googled it and it seems like it is not allowed to set lock on non-select queries - https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setLockMode(javax.persistence.LockModeType)

My questions are:

1) Why is it so ? I'm kind of newbie to DB stuff, but I've thought that i can use locking despite the query type.

2) What should I do i my case if i need ti provide concurrency for a lot of updates for one column from like let's say million of users ? From the point of Hibernate using.

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to approach differently. First take a lock on list of records you want to update. Once they are locked, the other transactions could not update those records that you lock. Following is the example taken from AxonFramework source code. It lock the token(record) first and did persist on the locked record later.

```
TokenEntry token = entityManager.find(TokenEntry.class, new TokenEntry.PK(processorName, segment), LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
if (token == null) {
    token = new TokenEntry(processorName, segment, null, serializer);
    token.claim(nodeId, claimTimeout);
    entityManager.persist(token);
    // hibernate complains about updates in different transactions if this isn't flushed
    entityManager.flush();
```

Another approach with explicit transaction calls. Example taken from LogicBig.com

```
  EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
  em.getTransaction().begin();
  log("write thread before acquiring lock");
  Article article = em.find(Article.class, 1L, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
  log("write thread after acquiring lock");
  article.setContent("updated content .. ");
  log("committing in write thread.");
  em.getTransaction().commit();
  em.close();
  log("Article updated", article);
```

For your +1 operation.

```
Restaurant res = entityManager.find(Restaurant.class, restId,LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);

   if(res.getVote()>-1){
     res.setVote(res.getVote()+1); // assumed vote is int
   }
   entityManager.persist(res);
   entityManager.flush();
```

Comment: Thank you for feedback, Zaw Htut ! But what if i need to perform +1 operation for one query with blocking ?